Passing headers with session.protocol.handle
When trying to pass a resolved url from inside a protocol handler, session.fetch does not pass any headers. Using request.headers does not work, as it is also empty
I have tried getting the headers from the the webcontext but found out setting host is restricted in the fetch api.
Ex:
session.protocol.handle('warp', async (request) => {
// ...
   return session.fetch(resolvedUrl);
});

